# What is the meaning of "Jump for it"?

Tags: meaning

Would you help to understand me the sense of the phrase "jump for it".
the context:
A group of people placed on the top of a skyscraper. And when they made their work, then, one of they say "jump for it" to people as a command. Then they all jump and grasp for the rope that get them down.

Comment: To 'reach for something' is to reach out to get it. To 'jump for something' is an unusual expression, but obviously means to jump in a (hopefully successful) attempt to grasp the rope etc.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Your description is rather odd, and there is insufficient context to determine what you mean.

Comment: What is unclear? I want to know the meaning of "jump for it" in the context above. A man say, being on the roof: jump for it and all people jump and seize a rope to come down. he've said it as a command. People worked on the roof where do their particular work.

Comment: Why were the people placed up there?  Why would they not just sit down and wait for some safe and convenient transport down, rather than jumping for a  rope?

Comment: This story is a little interpretation to the other story. It was got from the cartoon. For that not write the whole story I have written just a similiar situation.

Comment: In this particular context, *it* would seem to mean the rope. Are you saying that *jump for the rope* doesn't make sense? Is it the *for* in *jump for* that doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “for it” is an phrase that is relatively common when preceded by a verb of action in the imperative:

“The police are coming! Run for it!”

“Don’t be hesitant – go for it!”

“There’s a shark! Swim for it!”

The **it** is rather vague and depends upon the context, but it usually has the meaning of *“the [only] thing that will get you out of your troubles or difficulties”*

This understanding creates the meaning of "for" as, approximately, "because" (i.e. a subordinating conjunction of purpose.)

Thus

“Jump for it” -> “Jump because that is the thing that will get you out of your troubles or difficulties”.

And therefore "Jump for it" tells you that you must jump and gives the reason for jumping.

However, in another context the phrase may have its literal meaning:

A: How can I escape?

B: Use the rope!

A: I can't reach it!

B: "Jump for it! = "Jump in order to reach the rope." or "Jump in the direction of the rope."

Comment: Yes, in the situation got from the cartoon i guess i imagine it no correctly. This situation include yet particular danger for who was on the roof from the side. maybe because of that's used the phrase.